# Extracting the nth list item using HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, html, xpath, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

I am working on a web scraper project using HmlAgilityPack and C#. Please have look at the HTML code section which I am having trouble with. Since all the `<li>` items in the `<ul>` have the same class names for `<div>` and , how can I extract the full location (Town, City) i.e value of second `<span>` in the second `<li>` item?

```
<ul class="Menu">
  <li>
    <div class="item">
      <span class="name">Name:</span>
      <span class="value">....</span>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="item">
      <span class="name">Location:</span>
      <span class="value">
        <div class="location">
         <a href="....">Town</a>
         ","
         <a href="....">City</a>
        </div>
      </span>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="item">
      <span class="name">Phone:</span>
      <span class="value">....</span>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

This is what I have tried and failed:

```
var location = adHtml.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(
    @"//ul[@class='Menu']
    /div[@class='location']
    /a").Select(a => a.InnerText);
```

Writing `location` to the console gives me a Null Exception.

Comment: You know that the html is invalid? The `<div class="location">` has no end. otherwise you could select that

Comment: Oops, I didn't intend to leave that out. Fixed now

Comment: @TimSchmelter I did try to use this `div` for extraction, but I got a null exception instead. Do you see anything wrong with my code?